# Is it possible to hide dock on launch bar?

Tags: macos

When I open the launch bar the dock is always there taking up spaces. Is there a terminal command that allow me to hide this?

Comment: What do you mean by "open then launch bar"?

Comment: Even if you could hide it, the space wouldn't probably be used to display more icons. You can change the number of rows or columns with for example `defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-columns -int 8; killall Dock`, but the maximum number of icons per page won't be increased.

Comment: By launch bar do you mean **Launchpad**?

Comment: @patrix I guess so...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to hide the Dock is to press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Is there a specific reason you want to use a terminal command?

Comment: Option-command-D doesn't do anything in Launchpad.